# Speed up computation of a correlation matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, correlation

I have a question about calculating a correlation matrix and processing time. In this example I read a file test.txt

```
strm = OpenRead["test.txt"]; 
Skip[strm, String, 1]; 
test = 
  ReadList[strm, Table[Record, {85}], 
    NullRecords -> True, RecordSeparators -> {"\t", "\n"}]; 
Close[strm];
```

This file contains more then 200,000 records and 80 variables. I create a smaller file like:

```
test1 = ToExpression[test[[1 ;; 10000, 12 ;; 48]]]
```

The output look likes:

```
{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 79, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0}, 
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
 {0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 4, 11, 0, 0, 0},
  ...}
```

Now I calculate the correlation matrix for the first 3 variables:

```
test1215 = ToExpression[test[[1 ;; 10000, 12 ;; 15]]];
test1215cor = Timing[N[Correlation[test1215]]]
```

On my computer the processing time is: 52.9779. Now I do the same for 6 variables.

```
test1218 = ToExpression[test[[1 ;; 10000, 12 ;; 18]]];
test1218cor = Timing[N[Correlation[test1218]]]
```

I repeat this calculation for 9, 12 and 15 variables

```
test1221 = ToExpression[test[[1 ;; 10000, 12 ;; 21]]];
test1221cor = Timing[N[Correlation[test1221]]]
```

> 109.076

```
test12227 = ToExpression[test[[1 ;; 10000, 12 ;; 27]]]
test1227cor = Timing[N[Correlation[test12227]]]
```

> 284.39

When I plot the processing time, I obtain the following:

```
time = {{3, 52.9}, {6, 109.0}, {9, 284.3}, {12, 590.9}, {15, 787.8}};
ListLinePlot[time, AxesLabel -> {"number variables", "processing time"}]
```

[image]

So, if I want to calculate the correlation matrix for 37 variables, it will takes at least 40 minutes.

How can I speed up this calculation?

Comment: Why, after making, `test1` didn't you use it? Surely accessing `test1` would be faster than accessing the same data in `test`.

Comment: The computation time is based on the new dataset like test1215, test1217

Comment: the timing really has nothing to do with reading from the file. Consider thinking up a better title.   Is the input all integer? Have you tried `Correlation[N@matrix]`

Comment: Hi George2079. Thanks. You'r right!!

Comment: What happens if you apply `N` before `Correlation`?

Comment: Computations with exact algebraics such as square roots are much slower than computations with machine doubles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m = RandomInteger[40, {10000, 40}];
(a = N[Correlation[m]]) // Timing // First
(b = Correlation[N@m]) // Timing // First
```

> 5616.29
>
> 0.0468003

10^5 time difference, the result is the same to machine precision:

```
Max@Abs@Flatten[a - b]
```

> 3.10862*10^-15